# Regex for replacing all special characters and spaces in a string with hyphens

Tags: jquery

I have a string in which I need to replace all the special characters "~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}[]|:;'<>,./?" and spaces with hyphens. Multiple special characters in a row should result in a single hyphen.

```
var mystring="Need !@#$%^\" to /replace  this*(){}{}|\><? with_new string ";
// desired output: "Need-to-replace-this-with-new-string"
```

At present, I'm using this series of `replace()` calls:

```
return mystring.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-').replace(/\//g, "-");
```

But it's outputting this:

```
Need----------to/replace-this--------with-new-string;
```

where it's adding a hyphen for every special character in the string except for the forward slash.

Comment: Define 'all special characters' are they all the non-alphanumeric characters? A subset of those? At the very *least* could you post an example input-string and output string, without the instructions/requirements being present within either string? It makes it very confusing to try and read/understand.

Comment: characters to be removed "~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}[]|\:;'<>,./?" and  space and these all should be replaced with hyphen , the string is alphanumeric

Comment: All with a *single* hyphen in the places those characters appear, or with a hyphen for *each character* that is replaced?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var inputString = "~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}[]|\:;'<>,./?Some actual text to keep, maybe...",
    outputString = inputString.replace(/([~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,.\/? ])+/g, '-').replace(/^(-)+|(-)+$/g,'');
console.log(outputString);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ldwx4/).

Answer (score 8):

Going by your comment and example:

```
return mystring.trim().replace(/["~!@#$%^&*\(\)_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,.\/?"\- \t\r\n]+/g, '-');
```

or to replace *all* non-alphanumeric characters:

```
return mystring.trim().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, '-');
```

You might also add:

```
.replace(/^-+/, '').replace(/-+$/, '');
```

to kill off any leading or trailing dashes (at which point you no longer need to call `trim()`).

Example:

```js
function cleanUp(st) {
  return st.
     replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, '-').
     replace(/^-+/, '').
     replace(/-+$/, '');
}

var mystring="Need !@#$%^\" to /replace  this*(){}{}|\><? with_new string ";

console.log( cleanUp(mystring) );
```

Comment: The second one is a clean answer :)

Comment: How to replace unicode strings like घर-घरमा ग्यास पाइपः कार्यान्वयनको जिम्मा ओलीकै काँधमा

Comment: That's a different, and more difficult question. I'd suggest [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as a new question.