# How to convert unicode string to proper character using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

Here I have the following function to convert the string into a slug to make SEO friendly URL.

```
stringToSlug: function (title) {
   return title.toLowerCase().trim()
       .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
       .replace(/&/g, '-and-')         // Replace & with 'and'
       .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
       .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
    }
```

```js
var title1 = 'Maoist Centre adamant on PM or party chair’s post';
function stringToSlug1 (title) {
  return title.toLowerCase().trim()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/&/g, '-and-')         // Replace & with 'and'
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
 }
console.log(stringToSlug1(title1));

var title2 = 'घर-घरमा ग्यास पाइपः कार्यान्वयनको जिम्मा ओलीकै काँधमा !';

function stringToSlug2 (title) {
  return title.toLowerCase().trim()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/&/g, '-and-')         // Replace & with 'and'
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
 }
console.log(stringToSlug2(title2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here I have implemented the above mentioned function with two different languages. Function `stringToSlug1` with English and `stringToSlug2` with Nepali language. With English text the function is working fine but when the text is in other language above mentioned functions return only -. **Result I want to achieve from function stringToSlug2 is घर-घरमा-ग्यास-पाइप-कार्यान्वयनको-जिम्मा-ओलीकै-काँधमा**

Comment: Try `[\p{L}\p{Digit}_]` instead of `\w`, `\w` only matches ASCII (unfortunately).

Comment: I want to replace special character such as :, !, #@$$#@^%#^

Comment: Replace `.replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')` with `.replace(/[^\p{L}\p{Digit}_\-]+/g, '')`

Comment: Hi @Majora320 I got `it-t-t-p-pt-i-pt` from function `stringToSlug1` and ` -` from stringToSlug2 when using the regex you have mentioned.

Comment: Hmm, JS regexes must not support that. Give me a few mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18936783/5740382.

I have come up with a solution, though it is not good solution (I guess). I will filter some specials character with `.replace(/([~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}[]\|\:;'<>,./? ])+/g, '-')`regex instead of filtering all non-word chars with`.replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '')`. So here is my jQuery function.

```js
var title = 'घर-घरमा ग्यास पाइपः कार्यान्वयनको जिम्मा ओलीकै काँधमा !';

function stringToSlug (title) {
  return title.toLowerCase().trim()
  .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
  .replace(/&/g, '-and-')         // Replace & with 'and'
  .replace(/([~!@#$%^&*()_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,.\/? ])+/g, '-') // Replace sepcial character with -
  .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
}
console.log(stringToSlug(title));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the designers of regular expressions (the ones in JavaScript, anyway) did not think much about internationalization when designing them. `\w` only matches `a-z`, `A-Z`, and `_`, and so `[^\w\-]+` means `[^a-zA-Z_\-]+`. Other dialects of regular expressions have a unicode-enabled word pattern, but your best bet for JavaScript is to have a blacklist of symbols (you mentioned `:!#@$$#@^%#^`. You can do that with something like `[:!#@$$#@^%#^]+` (instead of `[^\w\-]+`).